# Arrays returned by xml2js do not maintain all the order

Tags: node.js, xml2js

When xml elements are bundled some of the order is lost.

For example, the xml I'm reading has elements that look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<b>
  <c n="1">
    <v n="1">
      <w>w1</w>
      <w>w2</w>
      <w>w3</w>
      <k>w4</k>
      <q>w4mod<x>a</x></q>
      <w>w5</w>
      <w>w6</w>
      <k>w7</k>
      <q>w7</q>
      <q>Mod7</q>
      <w>w8</w>
    </v>
  </c>
</b>
```

there can be any number of `<w> something </w>` entries and 0 or more `<k>something</k>` entries and 0 or more `<q> something </q>` entries.

But I need to maintain the order within the parse. When I use the following code:

```
    xml2js = require('xml2js'),
    util = require('util');

var parser = new xml2js.Parser({explicitChildren: true}, {preserveChildrenOrder:true});

fs.readFile(__dirname + '/Test.xml', function(err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null, true))
    });
});
```

I get:

```
  b: {
    '$$': {
      c: [
        {
          '$': { n: '1' },
          '$$': {
            v: [
              {
                '$': { n: '1' },
                '$$': {
                  w: [ 'w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w5', 'w6', 'w8' ],
                  k: [ 'w4', 'w7' ],
                  q: [
                    { _: 'w4mod', '$$': { x: [ 'a' ] } },
                    'w7',
                    'Mod7'
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

what I'd like is something like

```
w: [ 'w1', 'w2', 'w3'],
k: ['w4'],
q:[ { _: 'w4mod', '$$': { x: [ 'a' ] } }],
w: [ 'w5', 'w6'],
k: ['w7'],
q: ['w7', 'Mod7'],
w: ['w8']
}
```

etc

Is there some way to maintain the order of this information?

Answer (score 0):

The constructor requires **1 argument**: `new xml2js.Parser({optionName: value})`.
You provided **2 arguments**.

Try this:

```js
var parser = new xml2js.Parser({explicitChildren: true, preserveChildrenOrder:true});
```

You should get a preserved order in the `$$` key from the `explicitChildren`:

```json
v: [
    {
        $: { n: '1' },
        $$: [
            { _: 'w1', '#name': 'w' },
            { _: 'w2', '#name': 'w' },
            { _: 'w3', '#name': 'w' },
            { _: 'w4', '#name': 'k' },
            {
                _: 'w4mod',
                '#name': 'q',
                $$: [{ _: 'a', '#name': 'x' }],
                x: ['a']
            },
            { _: 'w5', '#name': 'w' },
            { _: 'w6', '#name': 'w' },
            { _: 'w7', '#name': 'k' },
            { _: 'w7', '#name': 'q' },
            { _: 'Mod7', '#name': 'q' },
            { _: 'w8', '#name': 'w' }
        ],
        w: ['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w5', 'w6', 'w8'],
        k: ['w4', 'w7'],
        q: [
            {
                _: 'w4mod',
                $$: [{ _: 'a', '#name': 'x' }],
                x: ['a']
            },
            'w7',
            'Mod7'
        ]
    }
]
```

Also this issue might be related: https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/issues/499 but it seems to work fine without the `charsAsChildren` option.

Otherwise, this library might help you: https://github.com/nashwaan/xml-js

Comment: how do you access the '#name' items?

Comment: `result.b['#name']`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Answer (score 0):

You can use [camaro](https://github.com/tuananh/camaro) for this. the downside of camaro is you need to know the structure of the xml before hand.

Here's how to do it

```js
const { transform } = require('camaro')

async function main() {
    const xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <b>
      <c n="1">
        <v n="1">
          <w>w1</w>
          <w>w2</w>
          <w>w3</w>
          <k>w4</k>
          <q>w4mod<x>a</x></q>
          <w>w5</w>
          <w>w6</w>
          <k>w7</k>
          <q>w7</q>
          <q>Mod7</q>
          <w>w8</w>
        </v>
      </c>
    </b>`

    const template = {
        items: ['/b/c/v/node()', {
            key: 'name()', // get node name of the current child
            value: '.' // get text of the current child. can add more field as well
        }]
    }

    console.log(await transform(xml, template));
}

main()
```

Output:

```
{
  items: [
    { key: 'w', value: 'w1' },
    { key: 'w', value: 'w2' },
    { key: 'w', value: 'w3' },
    { key: 'k', value: 'w4' },
    { key: 'q', value: 'w4moda' },
    { key: 'w', value: 'w5' },
    { key: 'w', value: 'w6' },
    { key: 'k', value: 'w7' },
    { key: 'q', value: 'w7' },
    { key: 'q', value: 'Mod7' },
    { key: 'w', value: 'w8' }
  ]
}
```